# Django - Tastypie POST (update) causing 409 CONFLICT

Tags: python, django, post, tastypie

I am doing an assignment where I need to interact with a Tastypie API. I have no control over the API, I have just been given the details of it and told it is set up to allow GET's, POST's and DELETE's only.

Example POST - works

```
curl --dump-header - -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X     POST -d '{"email":"test@someemail.com","tr_referral":"SomeFeed","mailing_lists":1,"ip_address":"192.168.1.23"}' http://api.somesite.info/v1/account/?username=test\&api_key=a0495db44f4gch749c4gf56906350f336571d94
```

Example GET - works

```
curl http://api.somesite.info/v1/account/202126/?username=test\&api_key=a0495db44f4gch749c4gf56906350f336571d94
```

GET Response:

```
{"birth_date": null, "city": "", "country": "nl", "email": "test@someemail.com", "first_name": "", "gender": "", "last_name": "", "lead": true, "mailing_lists": [{"name": "Classic NL", "resource_uri": "/v1/mailing_list/1/"}], "phone": "", "resource_uri": "/v1/account/202126/", "street_number": "", "tr_input_method": "", "tr_ip_address": "192.168.1.23", "tr_language": "", "tr_referral": {"name": "SomeFeed", "resource_uri": ""}, "utm_campaign": "", "utm_medium": "", "utm_source": "SomeFeed", "zipcode": ""}
```

Now here is one of many POST's I have tried in order to trigger an update of the record:

```
curl --dump-header - -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"email":"test@someemail.com","tr_referral":"SomeFeed","mailing_lists":2,"ip_address":"192.168.1.46"}' http://api.somesite.info/v1/account/?username=test\&api_key=a0495db44f4gch749c4gf56906350f336571d94
```

It results in:

```
HTTP/1.1 409 CONFLICT
Server: nginx/1.2.1
Date: Wed, 14 Nov 2012 20:42:35 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive

Email address test@someemail.com already exists.
```

I also tried POSTing to the following URL:

```
http://api.somesite.info/v1/account/202126/?username=test\&api_key=a0495db44f4gch749c4gf56906350f336571d94
```

That returned:

```
HTTP/1.1 501 NOT IMPLEMENTED
Server: nginx/1.2.1
Date: Wed, 14 Nov 2012 20:45:01 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
```

I need to update the record using a POST. What am I doing wrong?

Please note, I have changed some of the data e.g. URL's, api key, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought I should come supply an "answer" to this.

It turns out that what was written in the assignment document was misleading and I was not to update the accounts via a POST as this functionality was not allowed.

What they actually wanted was for me to DELETE the account and then re-POST it which doesn't seem like the best way to go about it as it requires two API calls for every "update" rather than just one. Couldn't even use the PATCH command.